# How to align category labels on xAxes in Highcharts.js

Tags: highcharts, alignment, categories, label

I'm new to Highcharts.js and what I'm trying to do is a column chart with categories label visible on x-Axis. 
I've no problem with setting my highcharts object to show categories as label, but I still can't align those labels to the right instead of have them centered between two tick marks.  The property 'align' applied to xAxis labels doesn't work if what I see as labels on xAxes are my categories. Is there a way to do that?
Here is my chart:

```
$(function () { 
    $('#histogram').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [5,14,17,9,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]
        }],
        xAxis: {
            categories: [0.7,0.85,1,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.6,1.8,1.9,2.1,2.2,2.4],
            labels: {
                align:'right',
                rotation:'-45'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you need this? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines.label

Comment: Thank you aet for your response. I'm afraid it doesn't solve my problem. I just need to set a horizontal alignment for the xAxis labels (that in my case are categories). I need the labels to stay aligned to the tickmarks and not between them.

Comment: Look at **tickmarkPlacement:'on'** : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the following option tickmarkPlacement :
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

> tickmarkPlacement: String For categorized axes only. If **on** the tick
>   mark is placed in the center of the category, if between the tick mark
>   is placed between categories. The **default is between** if the
>   tickInterval is 1, else on. Defaults to null.

Check the code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/kprqb4h2/) :

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: [0.7,0.85,1,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.6,1.8,1.9,2.1,2.2,2.4],
        labels: {
            align:'right',
            rotation:'-45'
        },
         tickmarkPlacement:'on',
    }
```